# Emberjs catch an event in a collectionView

Tags: ember.js

I am a little bit in trouble because I have a table that is filled with a collectionView (its updated every 2 seconds) and in every row I have put an event. But the problem is that the event is not catch when I click on the row and I don't understand why..

Here is my table with my collectionView :

```
<table class="table-conf">
{{#collection App.ConferenceParticipantsView}}
    {{#ifLead view.content.type}}
    <td class="table-conf-td">
        <div class="conf-participant">
                <span class="conf-lead">
                    {{view.content.name}}
                </span>
                <img src="assets/ic_group@2x.png">
            <br/>
            {{view.content.phone}}
        </div>
    </td>
    {{else}}
    <td class="table-conf-td">
        <div class="clickMe">
            <div class="conf-participant">
                    <span class="conf-lead">
                        {{view.content.name}}
                    </span>
                    <br/>
                    {{view.content.phone}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    {{/ifLead}}
{{/collection}}
</table>

App.HomeView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function () {
                $('.clickMe').on('click', function(e) {
            alert('click');
        });
    }
})
```

My collection is working well, and its populate the table correctly, but the click event isn't catch and I don't understand how I can make it works because its working fine outside the collection generation.

Is there is any manipulation to do ?

[edit] My final goal isn't to get just the click event, I want to display an accordion depend of the row you click. But even with the action helper its not working to slideDown the row in the table...

So is it possible to modify the DOM of a new row generated by the collection ?

Comment: Using `$('.clickMe').on('click', func)` isn't a good way to catch click events, because new rows won't listen to these events. Have you tried the action view helper http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/?

Comment: Yeah the actions helper works well, but to be honest I need to display an accordion depend on the row you clicked.. and even with the action helper its wasn't working...

Comment: My question is this one : is it possible to modify the DOM of the new rows ?